# There was a problem creating field: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: users, database

I've recently downloaded a Drupal website to work on a local host (xampp).
After importing the database, changing the `base_url` and running the `update.php` script, I managed to make it work.

However, after a few tests, I've found a bug: the add new field feature is not working, because whenever I try to add a field to the user, the dashboard shows the following message: `There was a problem creating field Comments: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`

How do I fix it? Is it database related problem? 
Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

After trying to delete a field, the website shows two messages, one success message and error message: the first is the following `The field Office has been deleted from the Employee content type.`, while the second is

```
Error messageException: Invalid field name given: field_mentorship_program is not a Field Collection field. in FieldCollectionItemEntity->__construct() (line 101 of C:\xampp\htdocs\website\sites\all\modules\field_collection\field_collection.entity.inc).
```

**UPDATE 2**

I was able to solve the problem by re-uploading the database as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Have you flushed caches? Have you tried adding a content type or deleting a field as well? Does the status page show you anything? Error log?

Comment: Did you try re-importing db?